# Out of Memory Error Excel Replace Function

Tags: excel, vba

I try to update a excel column with a little VBA Code.
The Goal is to replace relative Links with absolute links. Since they don't work in a e-mail.
Unfortunately the VBA Script already worked multiple times. But from time to time I get a "Out of Memory" error from excel. Even on my pc with 32 GB RAM and Xeon processor the error appears when the range is more than 4 rows. Since I need to update 800 rows this is not working for me.
Here is the code, in Column T are only hyperlinks or empty fields:

```
Sub replaceInColumn()
    Dim hLink As Hyperlink
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("'XXX'!T1:T800")
    Dim cel As Range
    
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
       For Each hLink In cel.Hyperlinks
            hLink.Address = replace(hLink.Address, "../..", "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites")
        Next hLink
    Next
End Sub
```

Does anyone know where this issue comes from and how to fix it?
I'm realy gratefull about any help.

Comment: Why don't you try defining the range like this: `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX").Range("T1:T800")`?